# Meteor publish and subscribe with routes

Tags: javascript, meteor

Hey I'm trying to setup a link show page in meteor but the data never gets to the view. This is pretty run of the mill but I couldn't seem to get it after I removed autopublish, any ideas?

Thanks

**iron router file**

```
Router.route('/show/:_id',{
    template: "show",
    name: "show",
    data: function(){
      return Links.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    },    
    subscriptions: function(){
      return Meteor.subscribe('links', this.params._id);
    }
});
```

**server side**

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

    Meteor.publish('links', function(currentLink){
      return Links.find({ _id: currentLink })
    });

});
```

**template**

```
<template name="show">
  {{info}}
</template>
```

**collection**

```
Links = new Mongo.Collection("links");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your router, try using the `waitOn` parameter. http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#the-waiton-option

```
Router.route('/show/:_id',{
    template: "show",
    name: "show",
    data: function(){
      return Links.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    },    
    waitOn: function(){
      return Meteor.subscribe('links', this.params._id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using helpers rather than the data function. Try using a helper to connect your collection to your template. {{info}} will invoke the info helper in this code below which returns all objects in the Links collection:

```
Template.show.helpers({
    info: function() {
        return Links.find().fetch();
    }
});
```

What does your Link object look like? Does it have an "info" field?

Comment: I thought the data function in iron router would find the link. @brettmclain  and the link does have an info field

Comment: the link does have an info field

Comment: I just edited my answer; you are correct. What does your Link object look like, does it have an "info" field? After the page has loaded, open up your developer console (F12 in chrome) and type this into the console: console.log(Links.findOne({_id: Router.current().params._id}));

Comment: If nothing comes back, then there is something else going on (this.params._id is not what you expect it to be, or that data doesn't exist in the database, or your subscription is failing or isn't ready yet).

Comment: no i have auto publish removed so i can't do that @BrettMclain